# Unexpected token C in JSON at position 0

Tags: javascript, express, github, npm, socket.io

im new to this so please bear with me! :)

I have found a project on GitHub I want to learn and work on to produce my own solution. It can be found here: https://github.com/bradtraversy/chatcord

When I have created the files locally I am trying to run "npm install" as suggested by the author. When I do that i get the following error messages:

npm ERR! Unexpected token C in JSON at position 0 while parsing near
'ChatCord App
npm ERR! Realti...'

Whats wrong?

Thank you very much! Love this place.

Comment: As stated in the error message, there appears to be some invalid syntax in the JSON. You could manually inspect it and try to fix it. Or you could see if there are any updates to the project or research whether others have ran into similar problems.

Comment: GetSet: Here is the package.json:
`
{
  "name": "chatcord",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Realtime chat app with rooms",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server",
    "dev": "nodemon server"
  },
  "author": "Brad Traversy",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "socket.io": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.2"
  }
}`

Comment: Inspect the actual *full* error message, then find the *actual* JSON file they are talking about. You give a partial error message in your post (which doesn't help your cause). And further there is no `ChatCord App` in the json file you just mentioned while the error message explicitly *tells* where the "unexpected token" is near.

Comment: The log file says the same:

23 verbose npm  v6.14.5
24 error Unexpected token C in JSON at position 0 while parsing near 'ChatCord App
24 error Realti...'
25 verbose exit [ 1, true ]

Comment: GetSet, I attached the actual JSON file in the message above. Its the same as: https://github.com/bradtraversy/chatcord/blob/master/package.json ... 

Why does it say "'ChatCord App" when its not used anywhere else?

Thx!

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. When copying and pasting from GitHub onto my local file, I pasted in the wrong text in the package-lock.json file. Got it working now. Thank you for the engagement!